Movie with Lee Majors - cars are illegal
I saw (most) of this movie back in the 70s. It was definitely an American production and in color. It may have been made-for-TV.
The premise, as much as I can remember, is that the United States has outlawed automobiles. A man (I think played by Lee Majors) is trying to get his sportscar (I think it might have been a Porsche 917) across the country to California, which has seceded from the United States and where cars are not illegal. Along the way, in addition to pumping gas from abandoned service stations and avoiding the local yokels, the man meets a boy and brings him along.

A quick Google search led to this movie, "The Last Chase".  Here's a bit from Wikipedia:

At an unspecified future time, the United States is a police state. A substantial percentage of the population was wiped out by a devastating viral pandemic twenty years previously. Amidst the resulting chaos and general panic, democracy collapsed and a totalitarian cabal seized power. After moving the seat of government to Boston, the new dictatorship outlawed ownership and use of all automobiles, boats, and aircraft.





Oh my goodness. That looks even more ridiculous than I remember.

Yeah, it's pretty cheesy!!!
